# Pandas Dataframe group by week

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas Dataframe which contains a set of fixtures of sports events with over a years worth of data.

I want to create a new column in the dataframe, 'round' which increments week to week so that I can work on a larger set of matrices (of the fixtures) round by round.

```
import pandas as pd
dta = pd.read_csv(...) #read data
indexedDta = dta.set_index(['Date']) #index the raw data.
indexedDta['Round'] = 0 #add in the new column and give dummy value.
indexedDta['Round']= indexedDta.groupby(by=dta.Date) #wrong
```

Comment: Do you need that column to increment 1 by 1 on each new week (i.e.: `...4, 5, 6...`) or coud there be leaps (i.e.: `...4, 8, 11...`)?

Comment: increment 1 by 1 ideally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you just need a new column with different integer values for each week, that are sorted by date, but you do not care about which values do they take, you can try:

```
import pandas


data = list(range(10))
dates = pandas.Series(pandas.date_range('2013-11-01', '2013-11-10'))

df = pandas.DataFrame({'dates': dates, 'data': data})
df = df.set_index('dates')

df['round'] = df.index.year * 100 + df.index.week

df
```

[image]

If you would like it to be incremented 1 by 1, maybe add:

```
df['round'] = df['round'].diff(1).fillna(1.)
df.loc[df['round'] != 0, 'round'] = 1.
df['round'] = df['round'].cumsum().astype(int)

df
```

[image]